# How to flush right margin contents on even pages in two sided document?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, double-sided, marginpar

In `report` class with `twoside` option, how to flushright the marginpar contents on even pages?

The image below was produced manually inserting `\hfill`. I'd like to automatize it.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]\marginpar{Lorem\dots}
\clearpage
\lipsum*[3]\marginpar{Lorem\dots}
%\lipsum*[3]\marginpar{\hfill Lorem\dots} % <-- desired output
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is using `marginnote` package an option ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,marginnote}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]\marginnote{Lorem\dots}
\clearpage
\lipsum*[3]\marginnote{Lorem\dots}
%\lipsum*[3]\marginpar{\hfill Lorem\dots} % <-- desired output
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the default for `marginnote` package is like that?

Comment: I'd be glad to accept your answer if no other one for `marginpar` appears.

Comment: @Sigur Yes exactly! that's the default alignment with `marginnote`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{
  \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\marginpar{#1\dots\hfill}\else\marginpar{\hfill\dots #1}\fi
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]\mymarginpar{Lorem}
\clearpage
\lipsum*[3]\mymarginpar{Lorem}
\end{document}
```

*Edit*:

The command `mymarginpar` just checks if the page is `odd` or not. If it is `odd`, the command insert the text and then `\hfill`, if it is not `odd`, then `\hfill` is insert before the text. The command `\dots` may or may not be part of the command.

Results are presented below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you add some explanations.

Comment: No sé ingles, por eso no explico. Sorry.

Comment: I compiled @Herbert's MWE and to worked. Then I edited the answer briefly explaining the code and the possibility to use or not `\dots` as part of the command. @Herbert, su respuesta fue una buena, gracias por compartir.